# How to convert "n" number of lines into .csv in python?

Tags: python, csv

Dataset (extract of 2 separate items, *n* being 6 columns per item):

```
1
No. of A
600
No. of B
2
No. of C

6
No. of A
500
No. of B
4
No. of C

...
```

**Using Python,**
What is the best method convert and output the above into a .csv that looks like this?

```
1,No. of A,600,No. of B,2,No. of C
6,No. of A,500,No. of B,4,No. of C
...
```

Appreciate all suggestions!

**Modified Answer**

```
body = """
1
No. of A
600
No. of B
2
No. of C
6
No. of A
500
No. of B
4
No. of C
7
No. of A
501
No. of B
5
No. of C
"""

temp_body = body.strip().split("\n")
parsed_body = [temp_body[(0 + i - 6):i] for i in range(6, len(temp_body) + 1, 6)]                                  

import pandas as pd

df =  pd.DataFrame(parsed_body)

df.to_csv('output.csv', sep=',', header=None, index=None)
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `\n\n` separated 2 different rows then 
you can try it like this:

```
 In [1]: body = """ 
    ...: 1 
    ...: No. of A 
    ...: 600 
    ...: No. of B 
    ...: 2 
    ...: No. of C 
    ...:  
    ...: 6 
    ...: No. of A 
    ...: 500 
    ...: No. of B 
    ...: 4 
    ...: No. of C 
    ...: """                                                                                                                

 In [2]: parsed_body = [i.strip().split("\n") for i in body.split("\n\n")]                                                  

 In [3]: parsed_body                                                                                                        
 Out[4]: 
 [['1', 'No. of A', '600', 'No. of B', '2', 'No. of C'],
  ['6', 'No. of A', '500', 'No. of B', '4', 'No. of C']]
```

Once you get list, you can make use of csvwriter using csv module in Python and write it as csv

If \n\n is not our case and it is in continuous fashion then you can try something like this (kind of a hack but maybe you can come up with something better):

```
In [43]: body = """ 
    ...: 1 
    ...: No. of A 
    ...: 600 
    ...: No. of B 
    ...: 2 
    ...: No. of C 
    ...: 6 
    ...: No. of A 
    ...: 500 
    ...: No. of B 
    ...: 4 
    ...: No. of C 
    ...: 22 
    ...: No. of Q 
    ...: 500 
    ...: No. of R 
    ...: 4 
    ...: No. of S 
    ...: """                                                                                                                

In [44]: temp_body = body.strip().split("\n")                                                                               

In [45]: parsed_body = [temp_body[(0 + i - 6):i] for i in range(6, len(temp_body) + 1, 6)]                                  

In [46]: parsed_body                                                                                                        
Out[46]: 
[['1', 'No. of A', '600', 'No. of B', '2', 'No. of C'],
 ['6', 'No. of A', '500', 'No. of B', '4', 'No. of C'],
 ['22', 'No. of Q', '500', 'No. of R', '4', 'No. of S']]
```

Comment: Hi Shashank, thanks for the response! 

What might the fix be, assuming that there are no double line breaks, but that the data is consistent, in that, every "7th line" is a new item?

Comment: @shongyanglow Have a look at answer, not best approach but might help you to think

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is consistent and clean, you can split your data on the double line break. And then for each item replace the line breaks with commas:

```
data = '''1
No. of A
600
No. of B
2
No. of C

6
No. of A
500
No. of B
4
No. of C'''

items = [item.replace('\n', ',') for item in data.split('\n\n')]
print('\n'.join(items))
# 1,No. of A,600,No. of B,2,No. of C
# 6,No. of A,500,No. of B,4,No. of C
```

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for the response! 

What might the fix be, assuming that there are no double line breaks, but that the data is consistent, in that, every "7th line" is a new item?